# Node.js and csv-express date format

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a way to format the date "YYYY-MM-DD" when exporting to csv using csv-express? I've google this for a good amount of time but found nothing. I'm using the latest version of Node.js, Express and MongoDB.

This is the default date format: "Thu Aug 09 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)". I just want this "2018-09-09".

Here's my query:

```
router.get('/exportMonthlyPosts', (req, res) => {
   posts.find({...}, {id:1, title:1, post:1, postedOn:1}).sort(orderBy).lean()
    .then(post => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename=posts.csv');
        res.csv(report, true);

   });
});
```

sample data:

```
[
  { 
    _id: 5b64c23eef5b9c5c60fa42a0,
    title: 'Test Post',    
    post: 'Show me the money!',
    postedOn: 2018-08-29T00:00:00.000Z
  },
  { 
    _id: 5afb58408341f161a0c96608,
    title: 'Test Post 2',    
    post: 'Show me the money!',
    postedOn: 2018-08-29T00:00:00.000Z
  } 
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: just transform the data before you export it.

Comment: Hi Lux, thanks for you response. I'm currently learning node.js can you provide same code? I'll update my question to include my query.

Comment: maybe show your code how you export it

Comment: Please see updated question, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you try this? `momentjs`

This is cool module.

https://momentjs.com/

You can do this.

```
router.get('/exportMonthlyPosts', (req, res) => {
   posts.find({...}, {id:1, title:1, post:1, postedOn:1}).sort(orderBy).lean()
    .then(post => {
        // update postedOn.
        report.forEach((r) => {
            r.postedOn = moment(r.postedOn).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        });

        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename=posts.csv');
        res.csv(report, true);

   });
});
```

Comment: Hi seunggabi, I'm currently using moment.js in this project. I've try doing something like this (moment(new Date(postedOn).format("YYYY-MM-DD"):1) in my select but it didn't work. I new to Node.js and not really sure where to apply your suggestion. If you can provide sample code it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: okay, provide to me about `post` detail info in your code please. I don't know post json.

Comment: Thank you, this work perfectly for me. Thank you for the example!

Answer (score 0):

you can transform your `report` to a new data where all dates are replaced by strings:

```
const transformed = report.map(line => Object.entries(line).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  acc[key] = val instanceof Date ? moment(val).format("YYYY-MM-DD") : val;
  return acc;
}, {}));
```

then just use `transformed` instead of `report`.